# How to import Metal in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, metal

I tried to use `metal_stdlib`, or import MetalKit, but it shows `metal_stdlib` file not found, and MetalKit didn't get rid of any error such as

```
Unknown type name 'MTLDevice'; did you mean 'GDevice'?
```

So how can import Metal framework? I also want to use `MPSMatrix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add

```
@import Metal;
@import MetalKit;
```

Comment: I have this same issue even with proper imports. `metal_stdlib file not found` No solutions here.

Comment: @wmakley Any solution?

Comment: @hanno Sorry I abandoned the Metal refactor of my project after realizing I would have to refactor my entire renderer class and the way it did most things. It was just a small hobby project to render a Mandelbrot set in GLSL, and I found it more interesting and fun to get it working in WebGL than Metal. I do think the answer below about not realizing MTLDevice was a protocol and how to assign it to a variable may be part of the issue.

Answer (score 5):

`MTLDevice` is a protocol, not a class. In Objective-C, you should declare your reference to it like this:

```
id<MTLDevice> device;
```